# iOS: Crash occurs while using takePicture method

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a custom `UIImagePickerController` and I am in need of `UINavigationBar` also in the same Controller, so instead of showing default camera capture buttons I try to utilize space in the navigation-bar itself, on the button action I tried to call take picture method but its crashed. what is the correct procedure to do.

```
    // prepare imagePicker view
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    isFront = YES;
    cameraType = @"front";

    UIBarButtonItem *takePictureButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:imagePicker.view action:@selector(captureImage:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(flip:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:takePictureButton,cancelButton, nil];

-(void)captureImage:(id)sender
{
    [imagePicker takePicture];
}

- (void) flip: (id) sender
{
    if(isFront)
    {
        cameraType = @"front";
        isFront = NO;
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }
    else
    {
        isFront = YES;
        cameraType = @"rear";
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;

    }
}
```

Comment: Has it been tested on real device?

Comment: You also need to add the code for -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info; method. May be there can be something for crash.

Comment: i have tested in real device its crashed and i have included all its delegate methods.

Comment: Issue solved, its about adding the target, i added the target in the overlay view instead of adding it in self.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a method from `imagePicker.view` which is not declared there.

Replace

```
UIBarButtonItem *takePictureButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:imagePicker.view action:@selector(captureImage:)];
```

With

```
UIBarButtonItem *takePictureButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(captureImage:)];
```